# Functional inequation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

Is it possible to find all smooth functions $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=1$ and for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ there holds $f(x)f(y)< f(xy)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; there are no such functions, because your conditions imply that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}_+$ you have
$$f(x)=f(x)f(1)<f(x\cdot1)=f(x).$$

**Edit:** The simple argument above doesn't hold for the updated question; clearly $f\equiv1$ is a solution, as is $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Nitpicking here: so the actual answer is "Yes", it's possible: there are no such functions.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy Much appreciated, I edited accordingly.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I'll accept again your answer if nobody finds a solution during the week (I didn't downvoted though, I upvoted).

Comment: @J.Mayol My answer makes quite clear that there is no solution, but feel free to wait. And thanks for the upvote :)